# $f(x - 1) + f(x − 2) $ and the sum of coeficients

Tags: functions

If $f(x-1)+f(x-2) = 5x^2 - 2x + 9$

and

$f(x)= ax^2 + bx + c$

what would be the value of $a+b+c$?

I was doing

$f(x-1)+f(x-2)= f(x-3)$
then 
$f(x)$

```
a = 5
b = -2
c = 9
```

$(5-3)+(-2-3)+(9-3)$

But do not think is is correct

What would be correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x-1)+f(x-2) = 5x^2 - 2x + 9$$and $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
for $x=1,2,3$ we get the system
$$f(0)+f(-1)=a-b+2c =12$$
$$f(1)+f(0)=a+b+2c=25$$
$$f(2)+f(1)=5a+3b+2c = 48$$
with solutions 
$$a=5/2,b=13/2,c=8$$
so $$f(x)=\frac{5}{2}x^2+\frac{13}{2}x+8$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = ax^2 + bx+ c$, what is $f(x-1)$ and what is $f(x-2)$?

Work those out, then add both expressions to equate to $5x^2-2x+9$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f''(x)=2a,  4a=f''(x-1)+f''(x-2)=10,  a=2.5$$

$$f'(x)=2ax+b=5x+b, 5(x-1)+5(x-2)+2b$$

$$f'(x-1)+f'(x-2)=10x-2, -15+2b=-2, b=6.5$$

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c, 2.5(x-1)^2+6.5(x-1)+2.5(x-2)^2+6.5(x-2)+2c=f(x-1)+f(x-2)=5x^2-2x+9$$

let $x=0$ on both side, $2.5-6.5+10-13+2c=9, c=8$

so $a+b+c=2.5+6.5+8=17$

Answer (score 1):

We know $$f(x-1)=a(x-1)^2+b(x-1)+c\quad\text{and}\quad f(x-2)=a(x-2)^2+b(x-2)+c.$$ Expand these terms, add them, and combine like terms via powers of $x$. Now you can get three equations in three variables by equating the coefficients of the left with the right since you know $$f(x-1)+f(x-2)=5x^2-2x+9.$$

Comment: So I have done:
$f(x-1)=  a(x-1)^2  +  b(x-1) + c  = a(x-1)(x-1) +  bx -  b + c  = ax^2 -2ax + a  + bx - b + c$


$f(x-2) = a(x-2)^2  +  b(x-2) + c  = a(x-2)(x-2) +  bx - 2b + c  = ax^2 -4ax + 4  + bx - b + c$
$

so $$f(x−1)+f(x−2) = 2ax^2 -6ax + a +4  + 2bx  - 2b + 2c = 5x^2 - 2x + 9$$ right?

Comment: @cMinor check again your expansion of $f(x-2)$. It should be `4a` and `-2b`.